# C++ Abstract Error

Tags: c++, abstract-class

## Solution

I'm posting the solution here so you don't have to scroll all the way to the bottom. Another user added a fix/patch to the repository for this issue. The fix is currently unstable so you'll need to install the unstable version of this project:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect
$ cd SensorKinect
$ git checkout unstable
```

## Question

I'm trying to compile `SensorKinect` manually for a hobby project I'm working on. The output of `./RedistMaker Arm` is beyond the 30k SOF character limit so I've added the [entire output as a multi-line comment to codepad.org](http://codepad.org/dQ0RegIF) for those who are curious. I've extracted the "important" parts and added them below:

## Error

```
$ ./RedistMaker Arm
Creating redist for Sensor v5.1.2.1
Cleaning previous outputs...
Building...
make: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/kinect/SensorKinect/Platform/Linux/Build'
make -C XnCore CFG=Release
make -C XnDeviceSensorV2 CFG=Release


... output omitted here ...


In file included from /usr/include/ni/XnTypes.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/ni/XnModuleInterface.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/ni/XnModuleCppInterface.h:33,
                 from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorProductionNode.h:28,
                 from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorGenerator.h:28,
                 from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorMapGenerator.h:28,
                 from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.h:28,
                 from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp:25:
../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp: In member function 'virtual XnSensorGenerator* XnExportedSensorDepthGenerator::CreateGenerator(xn::Context&, xn::Device&, XnDeviceBase*, const XnChar*)':
/usr/include/ni/XnOS.h:327:49: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'XnSensorDepthGenerator'
  #define XN_NEW(type, ...)  new type(__VA_ARGS__)
                                                 ^
../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp:339:9: note: in expansion of macro 'XN_NEW'
  return XN_NEW(XnSensorDepthGenerator, context, sensor, pSensor, strStreamName);
         ^
In file included from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp:25:0:
../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.h:39:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'XnSensorDepthGenerator':
 class XnSensorDepthGenerator : 
       ^
In file included from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorProductionNode.h:28:0,
                 from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorGenerator.h:28,
                 from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorMapGenerator.h:28,
                 from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.h:28,
                 from ../../../../Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp:25:
/usr/include/ni/XnModuleCppInterface.h:220:20: note:    virtual XnStatus xn::ModuleAlternativeViewPointInterface::GetPixelCoordinatesInViewPoint(xn::ProductionNode&, XnUInt32, XnUInt32, XnUInt32&, XnUInt32&)
   virtual XnStatus GetPixelCoordinatesInViewPoint(ProductionNode& other, XnUInt32 x, XnUInt32 y, XnUInt32& altX, XnUInt32& altY) = 0;
                    ^
make[1]: *** [Arm-Release/XnSensorDepthGenerator.o] Error 1

... more output omitted here ...
```

The file that is having the `abstract` error is [`XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp`. Here it is on github](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/blob/unstable/Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp) and below is the code itself:

## XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp

```
/****************************************************************************
*                                                                           *
*  PrimeSense Sensor 5.x Alpha                                              *
*  Copyright (C) 2011 PrimeSense Ltd.                                       *
*                                                                           *
*  This file is part of PrimeSense Sensor.                                  *
*                                                                           *
*  PrimeSense Sensor is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify*
*  it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published *
*  by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or     *
*  (at your option) any later version.                                      *
*                                                                           *
*  PrimeSense Sensor is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,     *
*  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of           *
*  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the             *
*  GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.                      *
*                                                                           *
*  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License *
*  along with PrimeSense Sensor. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.*
*                                                                           *
****************************************************************************/
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Includes
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "XnSensorDepthGenerator.h"
#include <XnOpenNI.h>
#include <XnOS.h>
#include <XnPsVersion.h>
#include <XnCommon.h>
#include <math.h>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// XnSensorDepthGenerator class
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

XnSensorDepthGenerator::XnSensorDepthGenerator(xn::Context& context, xn::Device& sensor, XnDeviceBase* pSensor, const XnChar* strStreamName) :
    XnSensorMapGenerator(context, sensor, pSensor, strStreamName),
    m_hRWPropCallback(NULL)
{
}

XnSensorDepthGenerator::~XnSensorDepthGenerator()
{
    if (m_hRWPropCallback != NULL)
    {
        UnregisterFromProps(m_hRWPropCallback);
    }
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::Init()
{
    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    nRetVal = XnSensorMapGenerator::Init();
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);

    const XnChar* aProps[] = 
    {
        XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE,
        XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_PIXEL_SIZE,
        NULL
    };

    m_hRWPropCallback;
    nRetVal = RegisterToProps(RealWorldTranslationPropChanged, this, m_hRWPropCallback, aProps);
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);

    nRetVal = UpdateRealWorldTranslationData();
    if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
    {
        UnregisterFromProps(m_hRWPropCallback);
        m_hRWPropCallback = NULL;
        return (nRetVal);
    }

    return (XN_STATUS_OK);
}

XnBool XnSensorDepthGenerator::IsCapabilitySupported(const XnChar* strCapabilityName)
{
    return (strcmp(strCapabilityName, XN_CAPABILITY_USER_POSITION) == 0 ||
        strcmp(strCapabilityName, XN_CAPABILITY_ALTERNATIVE_VIEW_POINT) == 0 ||
        strcmp(strCapabilityName, XN_CAPABILITY_FRAME_SYNC) == 0 ||
        XnSensorMapGenerator::IsCapabilitySupported(strCapabilityName));
}

XnDepthPixel* XnSensorDepthGenerator::GetDepthMap()
{
    return (XnDepthPixel*)m_pStreamData->pData;
}

XnDepthPixel XnSensorDepthGenerator::GetDeviceMaxDepth()
{
    XnUInt64 nValue;
    m_pSensor->GetProperty(m_strModule, XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_DEVICE_MAX_DEPTH, &nValue);
    return (XnDepthPixel)nValue;
}

void XnSensorDepthGenerator::GetFieldOfView(XnFieldOfView& FOV)
{
    FOV = m_FOV;
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::RegisterToFieldOfViewChange(XnModuleStateChangedHandler handler, void* pCookie, XnCallbackHandle& hCallback)
{
    return m_fovChangedEvent.Register(handler, pCookie, hCallback);
}

void XnSensorDepthGenerator::UnregisterFromFieldOfViewChange(XnCallbackHandle hCallback)
{
    m_fovChangedEvent.Unregister(hCallback);
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::UpdateRealWorldTranslationData()
{
    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    XnUInt64 nZPD;
    nRetVal = GetIntProperty(XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_DISTANCE, nZPD);
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);

    XnDouble fZPPS;
    nRetVal = GetRealProperty(XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_ZERO_PLANE_PIXEL_SIZE, fZPPS);
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);

    m_FOV.fHFOV = 2*atan(fZPPS*XN_SXGA_X_RES/2/nZPD);
    m_FOV.fVFOV = 2*atan(fZPPS*XN_VGA_Y_RES*2/2/nZPD);

    nRetVal = m_fovChangedEvent.Raise();
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);

    return (XN_STATUS_OK);
}

void XnSensorDepthGenerator::RealWorldTranslationPropChanged(void* pCookie)
{
    XnSensorDepthGenerator* pThis = (XnSensorDepthGenerator*)pCookie;
    pThis->UpdateRealWorldTranslationData();
}

XnUInt32 XnSensorDepthGenerator::GetSupportedUserPositionsCount()
{
    return 4;
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::SetUserPosition(XnUInt32 nIndex, const XnBoundingBox3D& Position)
{
    // set (we only support Z boxing for now)
    XnDepthAGCBin bin;
    bin.nBin = (XnUInt16)nIndex;
    bin.nMin = (XnUInt16)Position.LeftBottomNear.Z;
    bin.nMax = (XnUInt16)Position.RightTopFar.Z;
    return m_pSensor->SetProperty(m_strModule, XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_AGC_BIN, XN_PACK_GENERAL_BUFFER(bin));
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::GetUserPosition(XnUInt32 nIndex, XnBoundingBox3D& Position)
{
    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    // get
    XnDepthAGCBin bin;
    bin.nBin = (XnUInt16)nIndex;
    nRetVal =  m_pSensor->GetProperty(m_strModule, XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_AGC_BIN, XN_PACK_GENERAL_BUFFER(bin));
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);

    XnMapOutputMode MapOutputMode;
    nRetVal = GetMapOutputMode(MapOutputMode);
    XN_IS_STATUS_OK(nRetVal);

    // we only support Z position for now
    Position.LeftBottomNear.Z = bin.nMin;
    Position.RightTopFar.Z = bin.nMax;
    Position.LeftBottomNear.X = 0;
    Position.RightTopFar.X = (XnFloat)(MapOutputMode.nXRes - 1);
    Position.LeftBottomNear.Y = 0;
    Position.RightTopFar.Y = (XnFloat)(MapOutputMode.nYRes - 1);

    return (XN_STATUS_OK);
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::RegisterToUserPositionChange(XnModuleStateChangedHandler handler, void* pCookie, XnCallbackHandle& hCallback)
{
    const XnChar* aProps[] = 
    {
        XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_AGC_BIN,
        NULL
    };

    return RegisterToProps(handler, pCookie, hCallback, aProps);
}

void XnSensorDepthGenerator::UnregisterFromUserPositionChange(XnCallbackHandle hCallback)
{
    UnregisterFromProps(hCallback);
}

XnBool XnSensorDepthGenerator::IsSensorImageNode(xn::ProductionNode& OtherNode)
{
    xn::NodeInfo info = OtherNode.GetInfo();

    XnVersion Version;
    Version.nMajor = XN_PS_MAJOR_VERSION;
    Version.nMinor = XN_PS_MINOR_VERSION;
    Version.nMaintenance = XN_PS_MAINTENANCE_VERSION;
    Version.nBuild = XN_PS_BUILD_VERSION;

    // check if this view point is image from this DLL
    if (info.GetDescription().Type != XN_NODE_TYPE_IMAGE ||
        strcmp(info.GetDescription().strName, XN_DEVICE_NAME) != 0 ||
        strcmp(info.GetDescription().strVendor, XN_VENDOR_PRIMESENSE) != 0 ||
        xnVersionCompare(&info.GetDescription().Version, &Version) != 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // check if it uses the same device
    xn::NodeInfoList needed = info.GetNeededNodes();
    for (xn::NodeInfoList::Iterator it = needed.Begin(); it != needed.End(); ++it)
    {
        if ((*it).GetDescription().Type == XN_NODE_TYPE_DEVICE &&
            strcmp((*it).GetCreationInfo(), m_device.GetInfo().GetCreationInfo()) == 0)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

XnBool XnSensorDepthGenerator::IsViewPointSupported(xn::ProductionNode& OtherNode)
{
    return IsSensorImageNode(OtherNode);
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::SetViewPoint(xn::ProductionNode& OtherNode)
{
    if (IsSensorImageNode(OtherNode))
    {
        return SetIntProperty(XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_REGISTRATION, TRUE);
    }
    else
    {
        return XN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM;
    }
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::ResetViewPoint()
{
    return SetIntProperty(XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_REGISTRATION, FALSE);
}

XnBool XnSensorDepthGenerator::IsViewPointAs(xn::ProductionNode& OtherNode)
{
    XnUInt64 nValue = FALSE;
    GetIntProperty(XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_REGISTRATION, nValue);

    return (nValue == TRUE && IsSensorImageNode(OtherNode));
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::RegisterToViewPointChange(XnModuleStateChangedHandler handler, void* pCookie, XnCallbackHandle& hCallback)
{
    const XnChar* aProps[] = 
    {
        XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_REGISTRATION,
        NULL
    };

    return RegisterToProps(handler, pCookie, hCallback, aProps);
}

void XnSensorDepthGenerator::UnregisterFromViewPointChange(XnCallbackHandle hCallback)
{
    UnregisterFromProps(hCallback);
}

XnBool XnSensorDepthGenerator::CanFrameSyncWith(xn::ProductionNode& OtherNode)
{
    return (IsSensorImageNode(OtherNode));
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::FrameSyncWith(xn::ProductionNode& OtherNode)
{
    if (IsSensorImageNode(OtherNode))
    {
        return m_pSensor->SetProperty(XN_MODULE_NAME_DEVICE, XN_MODULE_PROPERTY_FRAME_SYNC, (XnUInt64)TRUE);
    }
    else
    {
        return XN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM;
    }
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::StopFrameSyncWith(xn::ProductionNode& /*OtherNode*/)
{
    // we assume the other node is the image one (this is the only one we started)
    return m_pSensor->SetProperty(XN_MODULE_NAME_DEVICE, XN_MODULE_PROPERTY_FRAME_SYNC, (XnUInt64)FALSE);
}

XnBool XnSensorDepthGenerator::IsFrameSyncedWith(xn::ProductionNode& OtherNode)
{
    XnUInt64 nValue = FALSE;
    m_pSensor->GetProperty(XN_MODULE_NAME_DEVICE, XN_MODULE_PROPERTY_FRAME_SYNC, &nValue);

    return (nValue == TRUE && IsSensorImageNode(OtherNode));
}

XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::RegisterToFrameSyncChange(XnModuleStateChangedHandler handler, void* pCookie, XnCallbackHandle& hCallback)
{
    const XnChar* aProps[] = 
    {
        XN_MODULE_PROPERTY_FRAME_SYNC,
        NULL
    };

    return RegisterToProps(handler, pCookie, hCallback, aProps, XN_MODULE_NAME_DEVICE);
}

void XnSensorDepthGenerator::UnregisterFromFrameSyncChange(XnCallbackHandle hCallback)
{
    UnregisterFromProps(hCallback);
}

void XnSensorDepthGenerator::FilterProperties(XnActualPropertiesHash* pHash)
{
    XnSensorMapGenerator::FilterProperties(pHash);
    pHash->Remove(XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_REGISTRATION);
    pHash->Remove(XN_STREAM_PROPERTY_DEVICE_MAX_DEPTH);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// XnExportedSensorDepthGenerator class
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XnExportedSensorDepthGenerator::XnExportedSensorDepthGenerator() :
    XnExportedSensorGenerator(XN_NODE_TYPE_DEPTH, XN_STREAM_TYPE_DEPTH)
{}

XnSensorGenerator* XnExportedSensorDepthGenerator::CreateGenerator(xn::Context& context, xn::Device& sensor, XnDeviceBase* pSensor, const XnChar* strStreamName)
{
    return XN_NEW(XnSensorDepthGenerator, context, sensor, pSensor, strStreamName);
}
```

If I understand this error correctly it's saying that something is trying to `initialize` this abstract class which isn't allowed. I'm no `c++` developer by any stretch so I'm curious as to how can I remedy / get around this to complete compilation?

## ** EDIT **

I have attempted the following fixes

- Added the following dummy method to both `/Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp` as well as `Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorGenerator.cpp`

dummy method:

```
XnStatus XnSensorDepthGenerator::GetPixelCoordinatesInViewPoint(xn::ProductionNode& other, XnUInt32 x, XnUInt32 y, XnUInt32& altX, XnUInt32& altY)
{
    return 0;
}
```

- When that didn't work I tried to copy `GetPixelCoordinatesInViewPoint` in from a [comparable Sensor class](https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor/blob/master/Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp)
- When that didn't work I copied both `XnSensorGenerator.cpp` & `XnSensorDepthGenerator.cpp` over from https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor/tree/master/Source/XnDeviceSensorV2

The error did not change after the attempts above. Since then I've found you can install `SensorKinect` on mac via a prebuilt binary so I tried the same idea but with a x86 binary for Linux; no success.

At this point I'm off to figure out a new plan of attack.

Comment: What appears to have happened is that the base class `XnSensorGenerator` defines a pure virtual function `XnStatus GetPixelCoordinatesInViewPoint(ProductionNode& other, XnUInt32 x, XnUInt32 y, XnUInt32& altX, XnUInt32& altY);`, which means that every derived class must implement it. However, `XnSensorDepthGenerator` does not appear to have a definition for it (at least it doesn't in the code you presented). You might be able to make a dummy method that returns a default constructed `XnStatus`?

Comment: @AndyG I started in on your suggestion and when I looked for `GetPixelCoordinatesInViewPoint`inside of [XnSensorGenerator.cpp](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/blob/unstable/Source/XnDeviceSensorV2/XnDeviceSensor.cpp) I found nothing. Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: Yes, this appears to the be problem. I noticed you're pulling the "unstable" branch. Perhaps you should pull the master. It may be more stable.

Comment: I'll try the stable-master now. Also I've found that `grep -R "GetPixelCoordinatesInViewPoint" *` from inside `SensorKinect/` returns nothing.

Comment: @AndyG Same error when compiling from stable vs. unstable. I'm going to add a dummy `GetPixelCoordinatesInViewPoint` function to both files and see what happens.

Comment: I tried dummy methods and went as far as copying `XnSensorGenerator` and `XNSensorDepthGenerator` from [a comperable primesense project](https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor/tree/master/Source/XnDeviceSensorV2). No luck yet.

Comment: Please update the main post with details.

Comment: @AndyG In an edit I've added all the steps I've taken up to this point

Comment: Did the error message change when you added the dummy method?

Comment: @AndyG The errors came out the same, still referring to XnSensorGenerator and the `abstract` issue - I triple checked to make sure I was editing the right files but nothing changed.

Comment: @Jacksonkr Did you add the `GetPixelCoordinatesInViewPoint` declaration to the `XnSensorDepthGenerator.h` and the `XnSensorGenerator.h` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an old problem, fixed long ago in different versions of the codebase:

https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect/pull/5

Comment: I found this patch earlier today and because I couldn't figure out how to patch my `git clone` I decided to make the changes by hand. The editor of the fixer made a number of changes to spaces/tabs so I saw a number of green lines and noticed they were trivial. Unfortunately this led to me missing the `header` addition. How would you apply this patch to a clone with command line?

Comment: I found one way which is to `git checkout unstable`. I have yet to figure out how to apply a specific patch but when I do I'll add it to my OP.